# I need to set the path in a VBA in Excel so a file can be used on multiple computers

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file that creates an order for our supplier, and I use a VBA script to copy the data to another file and format it in the manner the supplier uses. Now that is properly running, my boss wishes to use this method at our other locations. The problem is that the script is tailored to our local computer.

I need to change the path to the location the file saves in the script from our local drive:

```
 C:\Users\*User*\Desktop\
```

to a generic one like this:

```
 C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\
```

I've looked at several options but really am confused at the simplest manner of doing this properly.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
Sub Order()
'
' Creates Order form Visual Basic control
' Visual Basic script recorded 8/27/2021 by Me
' Copies order to Supplier
'
    
    MSG1 = MsgBox("Do you wish to create a new order?", vbYesNo, "New Order Confirmation")

    If MSG1 = vbYes Then
    
    'Copies data
    Range("M1:N300").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A3").Select
    
    'Pastes data to text file
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="C:\Users\*User*\Desktop\upload.txt", Origin:= _
        437, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
        ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False _
        , Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Range("A3").Select
    
    'Closes text file
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\*User*\Desktop\upload.txt")

    wb.Close

    End If

    'Opens web upload dialog
    MSG2 = MsgBox("Do you wish to upload the order to Supplier?", vbYesNo, "Upload Confirmation")

    If MSG2 = vbYes Then
        Const Hyper As String = "*URL of Supplier*"
        ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=Hyper ', NewWindow:=Tru

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `sPath = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("USERNAME") & "\Desktop\"` - there are other options too

Comment: I did find those, but they only showed basically what you have here. I don't understand how to employ that within the script.

Comment: I just showed you how to build the path... then you can use it like this: `Filename:=sPath & "upload.txt"` and `Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(sPath & "upload.txt")`

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the code on [Ron de Bruins](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win027.htm) website.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim WshShell As Object
    Dim DeskTopPath As String
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    DeskTopPath = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")

    Dim wrkBk As Workbook
    Set wrkBk = Workbooks.Open(DeskTopPath & "\upload.txt")
    
    wrkBk.Save
    wrkBk.Close

End Sub
```

Special folders are : AllUsersDesktop, AllUsersStartMenu
AllUsersPrograms, AllUsersStartup, Desktop, Favorites
Fonts, MyDocuments, NetHood, PrintHood, Programs, Recent
SendTo, StartMenu, Startup, Templates

Comment: Hello Darren, Thank you for your help. I tried this and I get a "Type mismatch error when it gets to the ampersand. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Type mismatch indicates that the wrong variable type is being used (i.e. not a string).  If that was the case with the `DeskTopPath` variable then the error would appear in the `WshShell.SpecialFolders` line.